# In iOS 5 TableViewController is not scrolling and not calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios5, uitableview

i ve upgrated to iOS 5 with XCode 4.2 version. 
since i ve upgraded i'm not able to create proper workign table view controller.

1) Table view is shown on the device, but when i try to scroll up, it crashes without any error message

2) when i try to select a cell , didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called.

`NOTE: the same code was workign for me before upgrating to iOS5.`

This is the code for TableViewController.m file

```
 #import "CTableViewController.h"
 @implementation CTableViewController

 @synthesize arrNames;

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
 {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
       NSLog(@"CTableViewController::initWithStyle");
     // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   arrNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Peter Frank Brauer",@"Robert Schneider",@"Winfried Walter Kem",@"Eugen Germen Bachle",@"Clara Weib",@"Heinz Guther Winkler",@"Roland Bendel",@"Swen Aschemeyer",@"Patrick Bodingmeier",nil];
 }

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    // Return the number of sections.
 return 1;
 }

 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.arrNames count];
 }

  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
NSLog(@"CTableViewController::cellForRowAtIndexPath");
return cell;
}

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"called didSelectRow method");

}

@end
```

Thank you, Please help
Suse

Comment: I got exact same problem, and truing to solve for 2 weeks now, and no luck :( if someone has solution please help!!!

Comment: Me too got the same problem when I was using `UITableView` subclass. I got it working after I've changed the class to a subclass of `UIViewController`. I did no other changes in the code.

Comment: Do you have the "all exceptions" breakpoint enabled? this should give you more detail on why the app is crashing.

@Ananth If you are using a UITableView in a UIViewController (not UITableViewController) you need to set the delegate and dataSource yourself (You also should declare that your view controller conforms to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols)

Comment: Yes @Moxy, I indeed checked out all those things. But I cant find what is the cause for it. The problem is solved on doing the above change.

Answer (score 0):

If it's crashing without any error message than it's probably a memory management issue and it is likely to happen because of some other part of the code, or even because a wrongly formatted nslog.

The compiler doesn't seem to notice a few obvious things like setting a fraction value for an int which will crash the app in an instant but without any meaningful error message.

Try to look for mundane things in your code and not just in the tableView implementation.

Also, is there any specific reason your are populating your arrNames with alloc,init (non-autorelease) instead of arrayWithObjects?

Also: Run the static analyzer! It may help. Keep the Run button pressed and an Analyze button will pop up.

Comment: The crash error I am getting here is EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Most likely its due to memory management, because of that darn ARC, I can't use the autorelease command.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted your source code into a fresh project.  A few things jumped out at me.

You are subclassing UITableViewController.  Try just subclassing UIViewController, and delete your initWithStyle method.

Make sure that in the nib, the tableview delegate and datasource are both attached to File's Owner.

If you are still experiencing crashes, then this code is NOT your problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem as him. But I can't resolve it at all, I agree that the code isn't the problem. But with all the break points and crash logs I see, I do not know how to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

How you can select a row if is crashing first?

By the way,the code seems to be not the problem.
Try this after restarting your Xcode:

1. Go to Organizer
2. Select the Project tab
3. Click on your opened project and DELETE Derived data.

Then wait for the re-indexing. (You can see the top bar loding and the code with new index target).

So like usual Clean All Target and Build.

It works for me in similar cases.
Hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

in My case it was controller instance declared locally and it was losing delegade so i declared instance in header and everything works.